# How to Change Page Source View?

Tags: javascript, html, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I am coding a site with Nuxt3 and I have a question about the source section.

[image]

When I inspect the item, it appears like this, but when I look at other pages, it usually shows 1 page. How do they do this?

I researched code obfuscation but could not get the result I wanted.

Comment: This code is just visible in localhost.

Comment: @Mojtaba The site looks like this when I publish it with Netlify